# Combinatorics 200 side convex

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A(1),A(2),...,A(200)$ be the vertices of a regular $ 200$-side convex polygon. Make the diagonals $A(i)A(i+9)$, where $A(i+200)=A(i)$ for $1\le i\le 9$. How many distinct of intersections are formed inside the polygon by these $200$ diagonals?